# Transformation(s) on a random vector to make its co-ordinates independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X=(X_1\dots X_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with **not** independent co-ordinates. **Then, must there exist a transformation (possibly invertible, so a diffeomorphism) $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ so that the co-ordinates $(Y_1 \dots Y_n)$ of $Y=\phi(X)$ are independent?**

If $X$ is normal, of course, the answer is yes, as making the covariance $\Sigma_X$  isotropic will do it, as uncorrelated and independent are the same for normal distributions. But what about for an arbitrary random vector $X?$ I'd guess the general answer is no, but then is there a characterization of random vectors $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that there exists a diffeomorphic transformation $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ so that the co-ordinates $(Y_1 \dots Y_n)$ of $Y=\phi(X)$ are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_i(x_1, ..., x_{i-1},\, \cdot\,)$ be the conditional cdf of $X_i$ given $(X_1, ..., X_{i-1}) = (x_1, ..., x_{i-1})$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
F_i(x_1, ..., x_i) = \mathbb{P}\left.\left( X_i \leq x_i \right|X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{i-1} = x_{i-1}\right).
\end{equation}
If the distribution functions $F_1, ..., F_n$ are continuous (e.g. when $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ has a density), $\phi(X_1, ..., X_n) = (F_1(X_1), F_2(X_1, X_2), ..., F_n(X_1, ..., X_n)) \sim (U_1, ..., U_n)$ where the $U_i$ are i.i.d. uniform.

The reason this holds is a combination of the [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) and the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)). Let us consider the case $n=2$ for illustration. Write $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0,1]^2$ for the map $F(x_1, x_2) = (F_1(x_1), F_2(x_1, x_2))$ and note that $F$ is invertible. The joint density of $(U_1, U_2)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
p_{U_1, U_2}(u_1, u_2) = p_{X_1, X_2}(F^{-1}(u_1, u_2)) \left\lvert \frac{\partial (U_1, U_2)}{\partial(X_1, X_2)}\right\rvert^{-1}
\end{equation}
for $u_1, u_2 \in [0,1]$. Now, the Jacobian term takes the form
\begin{equation}\label{lol}
\left\lvert\begin{pmatrix}
p_{X_1} & 0 \\
\times & p_{X_2 | X_1}
\end{pmatrix}\right\rvert = p_{X_1} p_{X_2 | X_1} = p_{X_1, X_2} 
\end{equation}
where the precise value of $\times$ is irrelevant. Plugging this into our expression for the density of $(U_1, U_2)$ we get
\begin{equation}
p_{U_1, U_2}(u_1, u_2) = \mathbb{I}(u_1, u_2 \in [0,1])
\end{equation}
as claimed.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate a bit, or may be give an outline of your proof that $U_i$'s are iid? Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more details. I did it for $n=2$ but the argument extends to arbitrary $n$ since in general the Jacobian is lower triangular. A nice way to think about this is to consider what the inverse transformation that maps the i.i.d. sample $(U_1, ..., U_n)$ to $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ looks like. First you generate $X_1 = F^{-1}_1 (U_1)$. Then, given the value $X_1 = x_1$, you generate $X_2 = F^{-1}_2(x_1, U_2)$ and so on. (the notation $F_2^{-1}(x_1, \cdot)$ is a bit awkward, it denotes the inverse of the function $F_2(x_1, \cdot) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.